# Why ScrollView auto top when scrolling down?

Tags: android

My `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView8"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ListItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btnbge81"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have about 500 child controls in `LinearLayout` called "ListItems".

Why does the `ScrollView` auto top when scrolling down?

Comment: why you not using ListView instead of ScrollView to 500 item ?

Comment: can you specify the problem more or add some code,And as above comment you should use listview.

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana: I have multi type control

Comment: You can use view type method to differentiate between different views.

Comment: Listview can't display multi level.

Comment: @DT ok again: multi type or multi level? If you have multi level check ExpandableListView, if you have multi type just use ListView. I guarantee you that you will run into performance issues with 500 entries in the LinearLayout...

Answer (score 0):

The `EditText` will scroll a `ScrollView` so it comes into view.  You have to implement `onTouchListener`.  There's an answer somewhere but in a nutshell this works for me.  You have to clear the focus from the `EditText` controls to keep them from scrolling into view.

```
public class SettingRecord extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener {
    // setup scroll views onresume()
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svRecord);
    sv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    sv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
    sv.setFocusable(true);
    sv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    etName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etName);

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {     
        // fix focus on edit texts scrolling
        if (etName.hasFocus()) {
            etName.clearFocus();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you read something about an EditText? You answer does not seem to fit the question...

Comment: You have a control that's taking the focus so the scrollview shows it.  I had the same problem with a scrollview and the above is how I fixed it.  I don't know what your going to do with 500 controls but it's probably scrolling to the first focusable control and not the top that's why you didn't find the answer when searching for it.

Comment: So you assume there is an EditText stealing the focus... Interesting, you should make clear what you assume to make the answer more understandable because there was never an EditText mentioned...

Comment: You said 500 controls I have a pretty good chance one was an edittext or some other control that can take focus.  Good luck with this

Comment: "You"? I haven't asked the questions. Please be a bit more careful who you talk to :) Beside that: Instead of explaining your assumptions in the comments you should really really add that to your answer because currently your answer only makes sense *after* reading the comments...